# How can I access multi-element List data stored in a public class?

Tags: c#, string, list

My first question on SO:

I created this public class, so that I can store three elements in a list:

```
public class myMultiElementList
{
   public string Role {get;set;}
   public string Country {get;set;}
   public int Commonality {get;set;}
}
```

In my main class, I then created a new list using this process:

```
var EmployeeRolesCountry = new List<myMultiElementList>();   
                    var rc1 = new myMultiElementList();
                    rc1.Role = token.Trim();
                    rc1.Country = country.Trim();
                    rc1.Commonality = 1;
                    EmployeeRolesCountry.Add(rc1);
```

I've added data to EmployeeRolesCountry and have validated that has 472 lines. However, when I try to retrieve it as below, my ForEach loop only retrieves the final line added to the list, 472 times...

```
foreach (myMultiElementList tmpClass in EmployeeRolesCountry)
                  {
                      string d1Value = tmpClass.Role;
                      Console.WriteLine(d1Value);
                      string d2Value = tmpClass.Role;
                      Console.WriteLine(d2Value);
                      int d3Value = tmpClass.Commonality;
                      Console.WriteLine(d3Value);
                  }
```

This was the most promising of the potential solutions I found on here, so any pointers greatly appreciated.

EDIT: adding data to EmployeeRolesCountry

```
        /*
        Before this starts, data is taken in via a csvReader function and parsed
        All of the process below is concerned with two fields in the csv
        One is simply the Country. No processing necessary
        The other is bio, and this itself needs to be parsed and cleansed several times to take roles out
        To keep things making sense, I've taken much of the cleansing out       
        */


private void File_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {      

        int pos = 0;
        var EmployeeRolesCountry = new List<myMultiElementList>();   
        var rc1 = new myMultiElementList();
        int a = 0;

        delimiter = ".";

        string token;

        foreach (var line in records.Take(100))
            {   
                    var fields = line.ToList(); 
                    string bio = fields[5];
                    string country = fields[4]; 
                    int role_count = Regex.Matches(bio, delimiter).Count;
                    a = bio.Length;             

                for (var i = 0; i < role_count; i++)
                            {


                            //here I take first role, by parsing on delimiter, then push back EmployeeRolesCountry with result
                            pos = bio.IndexOf('.');
                            if (pos != -1)
                            {
                                token = bio.Substring(0, pos);
                                string original_token = token;


                                rc1.Role = token.Trim();                            
                                rc1.Country = country.Trim();
                                rc1.Commonality = 1;

                                EmployeeRolesCountry.Add(rc1);

                                a = original_token.Length;
                                bio = bio.Remove(0, a + 1);                              

                               }


                            }                       

            }              
    }
```

Comment: You are probably instantiating `rc1` only once and add the same instance to the list. Your code is not complete. Can you please add the code where you fill the list? Make sure that you do `var rc1 = new myMultiElementList();` inside the loop where you are adding the elements, and not outside.

Comment: Declare this `EmployeeRolesCountry` in a public space. Make it a class member, Otherwise `var EmployeeRolesCountry ...` creates a new object every time you call the method.

Comment: It is good that you can add more code since you talk about `EmployeeRolesCountry` has 472 records but it is not seen where and how you added those 472 records,

Comment: Done - let me know if you need more clarification. And thanks for your help so far

Comment: @OguzOzgul your answer fixed my problem! I don't know how things works on here - would you like to create an answer properly so I can mark as complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

When grouped by multiple properties, this is how we iterate through the grouped items:

```
var employeesGroupedByRolwAndCountry = EmployeeRolesCountry.GroupBy(x => new { x.Role, x.Country });

employeesGroupedByRolwAndCountry.ToList().ForEach
(
    (countryAndRole) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Group {0}/{1}", countryAndRole.Key.Country, countryAndRole.Key.Role);
        countryAndRole.ToList().ForEach
        (
            (multiElement) => Console.WriteLine("    : {0}", multiElement.Commonality)
        );
    }
);
```

### __ ORIGINAL POST __

You are instantiating `rc1` only once (outside the loop) and add the same instance to the list.

Please make sure that you do

```
var rc1 = new myMultiElementList();
```

inside the loop where you are adding the elements, and not outside.

All references are the same in your case:

```
var obj = new myObj();
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    obj.Prop1 = "Prop" + i;
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

now the list has 5 elements, all pointing to the obj (the same instance, the same object in memory), and when you do

```
obj.Prop1 = "Prop" + 5
```

you update the same memory address, and all the pointers in the list points to the same instance so, you are not getting 472 copies of the LAST item, but getting the same instance 472 times.

The solution is simple. Create a new instance every time you add to your list:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var obj = new myObj();
    obj.Prop1 = "Prop" + i;
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Now one final thing. If before the `foreach` I group EmployeeRolesCountry as below, how do I make the Console.WriteLine print from the grouped data instead? It seems to print from original

`EmployeeRolesCountry.GroupBy(x => new {x.Role, x.Country});`

Comment: Grouping by two properties, you will get something like Key = { "TR", "Role1" } and Value a list of matching multi elements. Editing my answer.